# Swift IOS Display AR QuickLook preview of downloaded usdz model

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, quicklook, usdz

this is my first time trying to add an AR preview into an app (also my first time using the file system). I have been trying to implement a solution similar to that explained here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126377 however one key difference is that my usdz model is not in my main bundle as it is generated and downloaded from an external source at run time. I was wondering if it is possible to display a file stored in the apps documents or cache directory and how it is done.

The file is downloaded and stored in the caches directory as follows:

```
class ModelFetcher: NSObject{
    var modelUrl: URL?
    
    func generateModel() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/model.usdz") else {return}
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: request)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}

extension ModelFetcher: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("File Downloaded Location- ", location)
        
        guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else {
            return
        }
        let docsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let destinationPath = docsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationPath)
        
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationPath)
            self.modelUrl = destinationPath
            print("File moved to: \(modelUrl!.absoluteURL)")
        } catch let error {
            print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I then try to display the model using ARQuicklookPreview as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook
import ARKit

struct ARQuickLookView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var allowScaling: Bool = true
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ARQuickLookView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> QLPreviewController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController,
                                context: Context) {
        // nothing to do here
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
        let parent: ARQuickLookView
        let destinationPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("model.usdz")
        private lazy var fileURL: URL = destinationPath
        
        init(_ parent: ARQuickLookView) {
            self.parent = parent
            super.init()
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func previewController(
            _ controller: QLPreviewController,
            previewItemAt index: Int
        ) -> QLPreviewItem {
            let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("model.usdz")
            print(fileURL)
            let item = ARQuickLookPreviewItem(fileAt: fileURL)
            print(item)
            item.allowsContentScaling = parent.allowScaling
            return item
        }
    }
}

struct ARQuickLookView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ARQuickLookView()
    }
}
```

However, I receive the error "Unhandled item type 13: contentType is: (null) #PreviewItem" in the console and in the UI it reads unsupported file type, I have performed tests to make sure the file is in the location of the URL and I can even open it in preview on my mac so it's not like the file format or location is wrong.

Any help on displaying a model from a location other than the main bundle would be helpful, or perhaps a workaround to first move the file then display it.

Edit: After changing the preview controller function to

```
let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("model.usdz")
return fileUrl as QLPreviewItem
```

Now in the UI it just says "model universal scene description Package"

And in the console I still get an error however now it reads: Unhandled item type 13: contentType is: com.pixar.universal-scene-description-mobile #PreviewItem

Which doesn't make sense as that it one of the only types it supports

Thanks,

Louis

Comment: quick question: ```var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
request.httpMethod = "POST"```
I think you are trying to download, but your method is "POST"... 
can you change that bit of code ("GET") and let me know what you are getting

Comment: @Jokecoder It is an API endpoint that I created which requires sending of parameters in order to produce the model. The model is being downloaded correctly I have verified this. The issue is just getting it to display with ARQicklookPreview. (Well it will in the future at least at the moment it is just a standard model)

Comment: then, can we first make sure that it is NOT displaying the model. Can you add the model to the project and just try to show it? If it does show then it means that the error is in the saving/reading the model part. Sometimes error&trial helps a lot :]

Comment: @Jokecoder Ok yeah I just added it to the project files and still won't display even using the exact code shown in the topic I linked

Comment: ```func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourObject", ofType: "usdz") else { fatalError("Couldn't find the supported input file.") }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        return url as QLPreviewItem
    }  ``` 

I see that you are actually using the code from the docs, and if you are then the problem is in the part where it is supposed to show the object...
can you make a sample project and upload to github so I can have a look?